# Setting a variable to act as a function call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set a variable to either `.prev()` or `.next()`, for example:

```
   if(x == y)
       var shift = '.prev()';
   else
       var shift = '.next()';

   $("li.active").removeClass('active')shift.addClass('active');
```

I could probably get it working with `eval()` however it's a security hazard.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every property of an object can be accessed by using [bracket notation *<sup>[spec]</sup>*](http://es5.github.com/#x11.2.1).
`foo.bar()` is the same as `foo['bar']()`:

```
if(x == y)
   var shift = 'prev';
else
   var shift = 'next';

// or a shorter and nicer way: 
// var shift = x == y ? 'prev' : 'next';

$("li.active").removeClass('active')[shift]().addClass('active');
```

Comment: `shift` declaration is out of scope, no?

Comment: @Madbreaks: No. JavaScript only has function scope.

Comment: Interesting. Ok, but how about `var shift = x === y ? prev : next;` :)

Comment: @Madbreaks: Yep, I was just suggesting that ;)